# Can we disable the affect where Line Chart "show up" from the bottom

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js, Line Chart to be particular. I am trying to make it realtime by refreshing data after few seconds and the the affect where Line Chart "show up" from the bottom becomes eyestrain. Can you help to show a way to turn it off? just show the line. Thank you

I have been trying every single options provided by Chart.js but still no luck

Comment: You can disable the animation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#disabling-animation

Comment: It works, thanks, one more help needed: can you please guide me how to delay the tooltip, it disappears way too soon to read all the contents. Thanks

Comment: Tooltip has got the animation config as well. For instance, tooltip.animation.delay: [what you want]